# In Lua, how to call a function stored inside a table using the table index?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I  am ( lua newbie/3days) trying to call a function stored inside a lua table as in following code

```
function sayhello()
  return "hello";
end

function saygoodbye()
  return "goodbye";
end

funct = {
  ["1"] = sayhello,
  ["2"] = saygoodbye,
  ["name"] = "funct"
};

function say(ft,index)
  local name = ft.name;
  print("\nName : " .. name .. "\n");
  local fn = ft.index;
  fn();
end

say(funct,"1"); --  attempt to call local 'fn' (a nil value)
say(funct,"2"); --  attempt to call local 'fn' (a nil value)
                --  the Name funct prints in both cases
```

I am getting the error *attempt to call local 'fn' (a nil value)*
The name funct gets printed in both say calls.

Thanks

Comment: No need for semicolons in Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
fn = ft[index]
```

because

```
fn = ft.index
```

is equivalent to

```
fn = ft["index"]
```

Comment: And you probably want `print(fn())` instead on `fn()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is described as a common beginner mistake in the book [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html). If you make mistakes, you know that you have started learning.  The answer by @lhf is correct, but I just wanted to highlight the wonderful book [Praogramming in Lua] (https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) for other person who visit this question.

> A common mistake for beginners is to confuse a.x with a[x]. The first
>   form represents a["x"], that is, a table indexed by the string "x".
>   The second form is a table indexed by the value of the variable x. See
>   the difference:
>
> ```
> a = {}
> x = "y"
> a[x] = 10                 -- put 10 in field "y"
> print(a[x])   --> 10      -- value of field "y"
> print(a.x)    --> nil     -- value of field "x" (undefined)
> print(a.y)    --> 10      -- value of field "y"
> ```